# Native Ad API in Microsoft Advertising SDK for UWP not returning valid data in test mode

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-dev-center

I'm using the Microsoft Advertising SDK for UWP: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdMediator.MicrosoftAdvertisingSDK and want to add native ads to my App

Here is code that demonstrates the issue:

```
auto NativeAdManager = ref new Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::NativeAdsManager("d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab", "10043134");
NativeAdManager->AdReady += ref new Windows::Foundation::EventHandler<Platform::Object^>([](Platform::Object ^ s, Platform::Object ^ ad)
    {
        Platform::String^ Title = static_cast<Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::NativeAd^>(ad)->Title;
        Platform::String^ desc = static_cast<Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::NativeAd^>(ad)->Description;
        __debugbreak();
    });
NativeAdManager->ErrorOccurred += ref new Windows::Foundation::EventHandler<Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::AdErrorEventArgs^>([](Platform::Object^ sender, Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::AdErrorEventArgs^ e) {
        auto x = e->ErrorMessage;
        __debugbreak();
    });
    NativeAdManager->RequestAd();
```

Once `RequestAd()` get's called, the `AdReady` event handler run, as expected, but the problem is the ad data is nonsense. For example `Title` is `nullptr`, `Description` is an invalid String handle, `AdIcon` is an invalid image class, etc. The `ErrorOccurred` event never fires. There's also some weird output in Visual Studio's debug output window:

```
 info:get_AppId() invoked.  [Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::CurrentAppFactory::get_AppId]
The thread 0x3ce0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
ERROR:ChkHr(spStoreCommerce->Initialize(HStringReference(wszCV).Get())) (0x803f6107)    [Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::CurrentAppFactory::GetStoreCommerce]
ERROR:ChkHr(GetStoreCommerce(&spStoreCommerce)) (0x803f6107)    [Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::CurrentAppFactory::get_AppId]
 info:GetAppReceiptAsync() invoked. [Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::CurrentAppFactory::GetAppReceiptAsync]
ERROR:ChkHr(spStoreCommerce->Initialize(HStringReference(wszCV).Get())) (0x803f6107)    [Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::CurrentAppFactory::GetStoreCommerce]
ERROR:ChkHr(GetStoreCommerce(&spStoreCommerce)) (0x803f6107)    [Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::CurrentAppFactory::GetAppReceiptAsync]
WLID Error: 80860003Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA59024008 in Advertising.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Concurrency::task_canceled at memory location 0x00000064AFDFF228.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a known issue and MSFT will roll out another release of Ads SDK which should stop causing this native Ad issue. Please check this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/edf36f44-c042-4dfd-940b-759cac6bf44f/microsoft-advertising-for-xaml-native-ad-causing-app-to-crash-after-recent-window-update-?forum=aiasdk